# jFrame to jApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have a program that uses a `JFrame`. I would like to make it so people could play my game from a website. Is there an easy way to turn JFrames into JApplets?

Comment: Yes. Step 1: make your class extend JApplet instead of JFrame. Step 2: see what's broken and fix it

Comment: Does your current jFrame program subclass the jFrame or is the code in a different class and you merely create a jFrame?

Answer (score 5):

> I have a program that uses a jFrame. I would like to make it so people could play my game from a website. ..

Launch the JFrame directly off a web site using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS offers many neat features, like auto-update & desktop integration (menu items, desktop shortcut).

> ..Is there an easy way to turn jFrames into jApplets?

When it comes to applets, *nothing* is easy.

It is always a matter of dealing with how different (versions of different) browsers, on different (versions of different) OS, using different (versions of different) Java plug-ins interact with each other.  And that can often be summed up as 'poorly'.

Comment: +1 This [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) shows both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to code your application to be contained within a JPanel. Then in the main method create the JFrame and adds that JPanel to it. Likewise, you can create a JApplet that gets created and just add the JPanel. This way your Swing application will be generally agnostic with regards to the [top-level container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

Comment: Commonly known as a 'hybrid'.  Even when developing something intended purely as an applet, I will tend to make a hybrid, which speeds development.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a JFrame from the applet. This JFrame then is a new OS window, and not still embedded in your browser.

[Our program](http://www.fencing-game.de/en/account.html) shows an example of this (of both popping up an external JFrame (or JDialog) and having components inside the applet, actually). (No source available, though.)

Comment: While possible, this can lead to 'counter-intuitive' behavior.  E.G. I surf to a page, see a button with 'Open Frame' & click it.  The frame appears.  I figure the web page is now not needed, and close it.  The frame disappears!

Comment: @Andrew: You are right, this is the reason I show a warning about this on the HTML page.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not sure, there were no complaints until now. But we don't have many users for now, so I'm not sure.